# How to replace specific elements in a string given on argument(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i am trying to do is go through a string, choose a name, and a job title that is currently in string, then it will find the line that the job title is on, than replace the current name there with the new name chosen in the argument.

This is my string:

```
TV = '''
Tulleveien Velforening
leder: Kari
kasserer: Ole
IT-ansvarlig: Liv
parkeringsansvarlig: Kari
arrangementsansvarlig: Liv
hagekonsulent: Kari
brannansvarlig: Kari
'''
```

Then this is the function i am trying to run to actually perform it:

```
def Verv(navn, vervs):
    print("Tulleveien Velforening")
    for lines in TV.split("\n"):
        lines.replace(navn, lines)
        return TV
```

And this is what i tried:

```
Verv('Roald', ["leder", "IT-ansvarlig"])
```

But what i get when i run the program is just the list how it was in the beginning. The expected output would have been:

```
Tulleveien Velforening
leder: Roald
kasserer: Ole
IT-ansvarlig: Roald
parkeringsansvarlig: Kari
arrangementsansvarlig: Liv
hagekonsulent: Kari
brannansvarlig: Kari
```

How would i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I have added some inline comments which should explain the logic.

```
TV = '''
Tulleveien Velforening
leder: Kari
kasserer: Ole
IT-ansvarlig: Liv
parkeringsansvarlig: Kari
arrangementsansvarlig: Liv
hagekonsulent: Kari
brannansvarlig: Kari
'''


def Verv(navn, verv):
    # Created an empty dictionary to convert the lines into a dictionary which is much easier to manage.
    rin_dict = {}
    print("Tulleveien Velforening")
    # Forming a dictionary out of your string.
    for line in TV.split("\n"):
        if ":" in line:
            rin = line.split(": ")
            rin_dict[rin[0]] = rin[1]
    # Dictionary key replacement.
    for elm in verv:
        rin_dict[elm] = navn
    # Printing back the dictionary in your desired format.
    for k, v in rin_dict.items():
        print("{0}: {1}".format(k, v))


# The second argument is a list.
Verv('Roald', ["leder", "IT-ansvarlig"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, `Verv` is very wrong. Here it is step by step:

1. `print("Tulleveien Velforening")`

   - `Tulleveien Velforening` is already in the input string, so why do you need to print it again?
2. `for lines in TV.split("\n"):` - Access `TV` (from the containing scope), split it on newlines, and loop over each element as `lines`.

   - Ideally `TV` should be passed in as an argument, but it's not a big deal
   - `lines` should be renamed `line`, since it contains a line, not an iterable of lines.
3. `lines.replace(navn, lines)` - Replace any occurrences of `navn` with the entire line itself

   - `'Roald'` doesn't occur in the input, so this does nothing
   - Substituting `lines` doesn't make any sense
   - Probably you wanted something more like `line.replace(..., navn)`
4. `return TV`

   - `TV` hasn't been changed in the function
   - The return value of `Verv` is unused

Note that the `verv` parameter is not used.

Also note there's no output except `Tulleveien Velforening`.

---

Here's what you want to do:

(This is one possible approach. [Rineesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180685/4518341) is another.)

1. Loop over each line of `TV`. I would write `for line in TV.splitlines():`
2. (optional) If the line is empty, continue to the next loop
3. Check whether the line starts with any `verv` in `vervs`

   1. If yes, replace the second field in `line` with `navn`
4. Print the lines

I'll leave the implementation up to you.

Answer (score -2):

You should replace `lines.replace(navn, lines)` with `lines=lines.replace(navn, lines)`. replace returns a copy of the original string with the relevant substrings replaced .

Comment: `lines` is a local variable and a loop variable at that, so this will have no effect. There's a deeper problem but personally I'm not quite sure what.